# How to search by Month from a date in Laravel

Tags: sql, laravel

I'm trying like this:

```
$cost=DB::table('breakfast_orders')
      ->join('breakfast_costs','breakfast_orders.date','=','breakfast_costs.date')
      ->where('breakfast_orders.user_id',1)
      ->WHERE(' MONTHNAME(date)='June'')
      ->sum('breakfast_costs.total_cost');
```

or the transformation of the following sql might help me:

```
SELECT * FROM `breakfast_orders` WHERE MONTHNAME(date)='June'
```

Comment: could you not search using the created_at entry?

Comment: `->WHERE(' MONTHNAME(date)='June'')` Your quotes are wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are date helpers available in the query builder :

```
$q->whereDay('created_at', '=', date('d'));
$q->whereMonth('created_at', '=', date('m'));
$q->whereYear('created_at', '=', date('Y'));
```

So in your case :

```
$cost = DB::table('breakfast_orders')->join('breakfast_costs','breakfast_orders.date','=','breakfast_costs.date')
      ->where('breakfast_orders.user_id',1)
      ->whereMonth('created_at', '=', $month)
      ->sum('breakfast_costs.total_cost');
```

Comment: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1052 Column 'created_at' in where clause is ambiguous (SQL: select sum(`breakfast_costs`.`total_cost`) as aggregate from `breakfast_orders` inner join `breakfast_costs` on `breakfast_orders`.`date` = `breakfast_costs`.`date` where `breakfast_orders`.`user_id` = 1 and month(`created_at`) = June)

Comment: `whereMonth('created_at', 6)` June for 6

Answer (score 0):

```
$month = 'June';

$cost=DB::table('breakfast_orders')
      ->join('breakfast_costs','breakfast_orders.date','=','breakfast_costs.date')
      ->where('breakfast_orders.user_id',1)
      ->whereRaw('MONTH(date) = '.$month)
      ->sum('breakfast_costs.total_cost');
```

Comment: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1052 Column 'date' in where clause is ambiguous (SQL: select sum(`breakfast_costs`.`total_cost`) as aggregate from `breakfast_orders` inner join `breakfast_costs` on `breakfast_orders`.`date` = `breakfast_costs`.`date` where `breakfast_orders`.`user_id` = 1 and MONTH(date) = June)

Comment: For resolving the ambiguous issue, we need to provide the table name as well. If you need to compare from the breakfas_costs table, then please write 'breakfast_costs.date' and if you need to compare from the breakfast_orders table, then please write 'breakfast_orders.date'

Comment: Simply => MONTH(breakfast_costs.date) = June

Comment: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'MONTH(breakfast_orders.date)' in 'where clause' (SQL: select sum(`breakfast_costs`.`total_cost`) as aggregate from `breakfast_orders` inner join `breakfast_costs` on `breakfast_orders`.`date` = `breakfast_costs`.`date` where `breakfast_orders`.`user_id` = 1 and `MONTH(breakfast_orders`.`date)` = June)